# MS Powerpoint slide master keep content

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, templates

I've created a master slide as shown below with multiple lines in it (and different formatting). Here is a print screen of master slide.

> [image: print screen of master slide]

When (outside master slide view) I add a new slide based on this template to start building, I only see the first line, as shown here of a new added slide.

> [image: new added slide]

All other lines have disappeared.

What I would like is a newly added slide should have the same content as what's on the slide-master in order to enforce users to keep using that format. Of course it should still be editable, (so inserting text box instead of a placeholder seems not the option).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how PowerPoint text placeholders work. They control the formatting of each text level, but don't enforce specific amounts/types of text content. The usual way around this is to include sample slides in your template or theme file and instruct the users to copy those as needed to add new slides. It's not uncommon to include instruction text on the slides themselves (or rather just OFF the edge of the slides).

Comment: Ok, a pity, but thanks for your reply! Then I'll add them as sample slides.